# How to stream mp3 files via https, on Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I have an application which streams mp3 file from AWS server via https protocol.
It works fine on Android 4.4 devices, but not on Android 5.0+ devices.

According to this doc [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) I can't understand whether mp3 is supported via http/https or not.

Here is my code:

```
private void playSong(String songPath, final ArtistSongData data) {
    if (currentVersionSupportLockScreenControls) {
        UpdateMetadata(data);
        remoteControlClient
                .setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
    }
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.stop();
    }
    mp.reset();
    PlayerConstants.isMediaPlayerPrepared = false;
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(songPath);
        // mp.setDataSource("http://p48.ve.vc/data/48/32549/272565/Kede_Pind_Di_-_Jassi_Gill_-_Jassi_Gill_-_48Kbps_-_www.DjPunjab.Com.mp3");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioStream.MODE_NORMAL);
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mp.prepareAsync();
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Music player prepared");
            mp.start();
            PlayerConstants.isMediaPlayerPrepared = true;
            System.out.println("starting now ...");
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MainTask(), 0, 100);
            if (PlayerConstants.isHomeShown == true) {
                HomeFragment.changeUI();
                HomeFragment.setSeekBAr(mp.getDuration());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How are you doing it? Show us some code. I've streamed it using MediaPlayer and it works fine.

Comment: @TeoInke Hi.. I have shred my code. Please check it.

Comment: Ok. So what's the problem? Is it just not being played, or is there any exception being thrown?

Comment: MediaPlayer gives this error - Android MediaPlayer: error (1, -<some code>) while prepareasync and onPrepared() method is not called.

Comment: Please, post the stack trace

Comment: https should work. I do the same thing over s3 urls. The only problem with http is on a very old version of Android, I think < 9. That was the only time I put in place a workaround.